# Atoms in motion - It's known that heat is related only with the movement

Tags: homework-and-exercises

It's known that heat is related only with the movement of particles inside the body. What is the difference between hot, stationary ball baseball and the ball moving quickly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, de difference is in the direction of the atoms. The atoms in a hot, stationary ball move around randomly (the kinetic energy of the atoms is in their vibrational and rotational motion), whereas all atoms in a moving ball move in the same direction.

Comment: So easy exercise and so much I thought about it.

Comment: Unless the baseball is so hot that is has melted or evaporated, the motion of the atoms is not Brownian.

Comment: @pela You are of course right, I glossed over that too quickly. I will edit my answer to reflect this, thank you.

Comment: @pela However, if you consider an inflatable ball (such as a football), the motion of the atoms inside the bal _is_ Brownian.

Comment: True, although those motions hardly affects the ball's temperature.

Comment: @pela The inverse is true though: the ball's temperature affects those motions.

Comment: @LSchoon: Definitely; the air inside the ball, and the ball's outer material, will (try to) be in thermodynamical equilibrium, but it will be dominated by the outer material due to it's much larger mass.